# How to grammatically explain this sentence?

Tags: grammar, articles, coordinating-conjunctions

> No compassion for the suffering or willingness to engage in dialogue with feminism.

I know it can be paraphrased as: "[He] has neither compassion [for women's suffering], nor willingness to engage in dialogue with feminism."
But, I'm wondering about how to use "the" because the definite article seems to me to join two nouns—"suffering" and "willingness"— together.

1. In the sentence above, the coordinate conjunction joining "compassion" and "willingness" should be "or," not "nor"?
2. Is an article on "willingness" unnecessary? Or, it must not be put?

Comment: No. << He has no [compassion for the suffering] or [willingness to engage in dialogue with feminism]. >>  He has no A or B. cf << He has no bread or butter. >>

Comment: There is no subject verb predicate. It is not a sentence. Just a phrase. "No compassion for the suffering" doesn't fit with the rest of the phrase.

Comment: This half sentence assumes that feminism means women, which it doesn't.

Comment: No compassion for the suffering [of women] or willingness to engage in dialogue with feminism. Now it makes sense, at least.

Comment: _The suffering_ means _people who are suffering_ (maybe specifically women, depending on context).